# illumination on boot

Tags: login-screen

I have a problem on both my Ubuntu PC and laptop
on boot the screen illuminates for 1 second and then goes blank/dark

if I power off/on the screen will illuminate for 1 second also

how do I make the screen stay illuminated?

Comment: please transmit the tech support solution to my e-mail oxide1984@gmail.com

Comment: Answers to particular questions only get posted on the question page itself. This works the same on all sites across Stack Exchange network, including askubuntu.com.  However, there's an option to subscribe to question RSS feed if that's suitable for you.

Comment: What also would help if you included Ubuntu version in the question. Thanks and welcome to the site !

Comment: Does it work on another OS?

Comment: problem still not solved - any advice is welcome?

Comment: ??????????????????????????????????????????